# twitter popover - apply different css class for different popovers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I am using [bootstrap popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) to display data when the user mouses over a link / checkbox/ data.

**How do I add a separate css class in my html to different popovers to ensure that specific popovers are correctly displayed.**

The css class that I want to add to my html code below is also shown below and called **popover_margin_left**.

Here is my html code:

```
<span style="cursor: pointer;"
      rel="popover"
      data-content="{% trans 'The Test Details that should be included in your document is the data and information that you want displayed to all team members.' %} {% trans 'The Test Details that should be included in your document is the data and information that you want displayed to all team members.' %} {% trans 'The Test Details that should be included in your document is the data and information that you want displayed to all team members.' %}"
      data-original-title="{% trans 'Test Details' %}"
      data-placement="right">
    <input type="checkbox" name="TestDetails" checked="checked" readonly="true" disabled="false" class="checkbox_resize" >&nbsp;
        {% trans "Test Details" %}</span>
    </input>
</span>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
/* change default bootstrap popover width & z-index */
.popover {
    direction: rtl;
    min-width: 375px;
    position: fixed;
    word-break: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    z-index: 9999;  /* maintain a high z-index to bring the popover in the breadcrumbs forward */

    background-color: khaki;
}

.popover_margin_left {
    margin-left: -12px;
}
```

Comment: I think you can add `class:popover_margin_right` to your html. add it in that tag where you want to add.

Comment: I have tried that. Unless you mean something different - perhaps you can give me an example.

Comment: did you use `!important` in your css like `.popover_margin_left { margin-left : -12px!important; }`

Comment: Always try to avoid using `!important` !!   @user1261774 create a **JSFiddle** if you can, that'll be more helpful

Comment: amit singh - but how do I apply the css class to the popover??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the following css classes to your custom.css page, then there can be different padding values used for the different data-placement values of the popovers.

```
.popover.bottom {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    margin-top: 18px;
}

.popover.right {
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-left: 17px;
}

.popover.left {
    background-color: gold;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.popover.top {
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

For example popovers with a data-placement="right" will be offset by 17px and data-placement="bottom" will be offset by 18px.

Also, the above css classes will apply a different background colors to the different data-placement values of the popovers so you can visually see the differnt css classes at work.

Hope that this helps.